# folding a list of classes to a single, comma separated string (in Scala)

Tags: scala, foldleft

I have a need to take a list of case classes and convert them to a to a single, comma separated string (with no heading or tailing comma).

```
case class State(name: String)

def toLine(states: State*): String = {
}
```

so, toLine(State("one"), State("two"), State("three")) should return one,two,three

here is what I thought of. any better way?

```
def toLine(states: State*): String = {
  states match {
    case s if s.isEmpty => throw new Exception
    case s => s.tail.foldLeft(s.head.name)(_+","+_) 
  }
}
```

is there a way to guaranty there will be at least one value in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mkString`:

```
def toLine(states: State*): String = states.map(_.name).mkString(",")
```

if you need to ensure at least one element you can do:

```
def toLine(state: State, states: State*) = (state +: states).map(_.name).mkString(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Scala's collections provide a function to do just this: `states.map(_.name).mkString(",")`

If you want to ensure that `toLine` is always called with at least one value, you can do this:

```
def toLine(state: State, states: State*): String = {
  states.map(_.name).mkString(",")
}
```

This will move that check to the type system, rather than doing so at runtime.

Comment: interestingly, running your code gave me this:
scala> def toLine(state: State, states: State*): String = {
     |   states.mkString(",")
     | }
toLine: (state: State, states: State*)String

scala> toLine(State("one"), State("two"), State("three"))
res0: String = State(two),State(three)

Comment: Forgot to map the name.